# Color and Text Sizes Suggestions

Tags: website-design, design, color-scheme, font-sizes, portfolio

This is my first time on this website and I wanted to get some suggestions for my portfolio website.

I just bought the domain so I'm using my IP Address. Here is my website ([click me](http://43.255.154.44/~robertsoriano/))

My website is not yet finished, but before everything I want get some suggestions from you guys about the colors, font sizes and everything so I can make it better before going live.

I'm using MaterializeCSS and Angular by the way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When it comes to color-theme(s) I'd suggest looking at what colors represent what in the culture of your portfolio's target-audience (UX 101 is to always make sure you research your target-audience). Here is a simple breakdown that I assume is relevant (I haven't researched that field particularly much, but it seems to be relevant: [**Colours by culture (hosted on Pintrest..)**](https://kr.pinterest.com/pin/164592561357882169/)

So consider what your market is (remember your portfolio is a means to sell your product: yourself).

In addition to above I'd also consider cleaning up your design by making it more readable and focus on what is important in a portfolio; if you are a developer then put focus on displaying projects you have worked on and less on flashy designs. One way of further putting focus on your projects could be to put your projects on top of your work process as that would be the first thing the viewer sees.

Generally speaking your portfolio looks OK, but you need to clean it up. As mentioned above, keep in mind that your portfolio's goal is to sell YOUR skills, not necessarily to display them. Imho a sales pitch (which basically a portfolio is) should be kept simplistic and on point, focused on your target audience and what your research of them / what you believe is important for them.